# unable to initialize docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, hyper-v, docker-desktop

I am trying to setup an 8-node cluster with 5 manager nodes where 2 of those manager nodes are on Windows boxes.

On the Windows box I execute:
`docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.10.10.100`

I received a message **must specify a listening address because the address to advertise is not recognized**

Then, I execute:
`docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.10.10.100 --listener-addr 127.0.0.1:2777`

It appears to create a swarm but when I pass the token to the worker node I receive **connection refused** which makes sense because, for some reason, the 2777 is not open on the Windows box.

If on the other hand I execute:
`docker swarm init`

The token that I receive has a 192.168.65.3 address which does not exist on ANY interface of mean.

**NOTE: This all happens on a Windows box with Linux containers**

If I switch to Windows Containers everything works but I need to use Windows Containers which I do not want to do.

Does anyone have any ideas ? I think this has something to do with Hyper-V.

Comment: Try this command to ensure the port is open on the Windows box: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name = "Allow incoming on 2777" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=2777`